# On mixed $p$-adic Hodge theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, resolution-of-singularities, p-adic-hodge-theory, mixed-hodge-structure

Does mixed $p$-adic Hodge theory exist? Can we extend the scope of comparison theorems using simplicial resolutions a la Deligne? Do we get 3 opposite filtrations as in classical mixed Hodge theory, or some other gadget?

Comment: @schematic_boi: [There are curently](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/330689/timeline) 4 rejected edit attempts (out of 4) of yours; this is your 5th attempt at playing with the tags of this question. Could you please stop doing this?

Comment: @AlexM. but I genuinely thought that my edits were relevant. Somehow each time they are rejected. I really do not understand (I do not understand the message they give me).

Comment: There's a weight filtration in rigid cohomology.